# Use Category for Custom Post Type - But Need Another Separate Archive Page too

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I have created custom post type called "Articles" and I have include "Category" for that post type too.

Let say I have a category called "ABC."

When I go domain.com/category/ABC it display **both posts and articles**. It is perfectly **fine**.

But I want archive page for Article Categories too.....

I mean something like "domain.com/article/category/ABC"... So this archive page will show only articles which are on ABC Category.

Comment: why not you create custom taxonomy for article post type?

Comment: @1naveengiri Because when land to 'domain.com/category/ABC' should display both posts and custom type posts called articles in ABC category